# How to write a javascript function that takes an array with names and scores, and returns array with letter grades and students?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've been stuck for days. Please help! new to javascript

first I mapped the students scores, and got an array of just the number scores. Then I wrote a if/else function to take the student score and convert it to a letter grade. But how can I take this array of letter grade and list out all the students that got each grade? and then write this in es6 into the getStudentsByGrade const??

```
 var studentScores = students.map(function (student) {
   return student.score;
 })
 console.log(studentScores);

 function toLetterGrade(studentScores) {
   var textG = '';
   var result = [];
   for (i = 0; i < studentScores.length; i++) {
     textG = '';
     if (studentScores[i] >= 90) {
       textG = "A";
     } else if (studentScores[i] >= 80) {
       textG = "B";
     } else if (studentScores[i] >= 60) {
       textG = "C";
     } else if (studentScores[i] >= 50) {
       textG = "D";
     } else if (studentScores[i] >= 32) {
       textG = "E";
     } else {
       textG = "F";
     }
     result.push(textG);
   }
   return result;
 }

 console.log(toLetterGrade(studentScores));
```

Given a list of students with a name and a score, write a function `getStudentsByGrade` that takes in an array of students and a set of grade boundaries and gives you an gives you an object with a list of grades and the names of students for each grade.

the output should be:

```
{
  A: ['Dan'],
  C: ['Emily', 'Daisy'],
  E: ['Brendan']
}
```

And must be written inside the following

```
const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => {    
  // solution in here    
}
```

Given:

```
const students = [{name: 'Daisy', score: 65}, 
                  {name: 'Dan', score: 99}, 
                  {name: 'Emily', score: 77}, 
                  {name: 'Brendan', score: 49}];

const gradeBoundaries = {A: 90, B: 80, C: 60, D: 50, E: 32, F: 0};

const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => {    
  // How do I do this?    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to transform an input array into an object indexed by grade - the appropriate tool to transform an array into an object (or any sort of single value) is `reduce`. You might separate out the code that turns the score into a letter grade into its own function, for better readability. For each student, get their appropriate letter grade, and then add that student's name to that grade array in the accumulator. If that grade doesn't exist yet in the accumulator, create it as a new array first:

```js
const makeGetGrade = gradeBoundaries => {
  const gradeBoundaryArr = Object.entries(gradeBoundaries)
    .map(([grade, cutoff]) => ({ grade, cutoff }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.cutoff - a.cutoff);
  return findGrade => gradeBoundaryArr
    .find(({ grade, cutoff }) => findGrade > cutoff)
    .grade;
};

const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => {
  const getGrade = makeGetGrade(gradeBoundaries);
  return students.reduce((a, { name, score }) => {
    const grade = getGrade(score);
    if (!a[grade]) a[grade] = [];
    a[grade].push(name);
    return a;
  }, {});
};


const students=[{name:'Daisy',score:65,},{name:'Dan',score:99,},{name:'Emily',score:77},{name:'Brendan',score:49}];

const possibleGradeBoundaries = {
  A: 90,
  B: 80,
  C: 60,
  D: 50,
  E: 32,
  F: 0,
};
console.log(getStudentsByGrade(students, possibleGradeBoundaries));
```

Comment: How would this translate into const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => {

// How do I do this? the question requires the solution to be written here

}

Comment: Your original code implied that you're able to hard-code the grade boundaries - is that not the case?

Comment: No  but that was the only way i knew how. The original question was to write the function inside the given const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => { ***insert code here }

Comment: Make a function to turn the `gradeBoundaries` into an easily-searchable array, then call that function for each student - see edit

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this. With the help of Array.filter and Object.keys, you can easily get your result in the specified format.

```
const getStudentsByGrade = (students, gradeBoundaries) => {
  let result = {};
  let letterGrades = Object.keys(gradeBoundaries);

  letterGrades.forEach((letterGrade, index) => {
    result[letterGrade] = students.filter(student => {
      if (student.score >= gradeBoundaries[letterGrade]) {
        if (index > 0) {
          let higherLetterGrade = letterGrades[index - 1];
          if (student.score < gradeBoundaries[higherLetterGrade]) {
            return student.name;
          }
        } else {
          return student.name;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return result;
}
```

Then simply invoke the function with data to see the result:

```
let result = getStudentsByGrade(students, gradeBoundaries);
console.log(result);
```

This should be the result output:

```
{
  "A":[
    {
      "name":"Dan",
      "score":99
    }
  ],
  "B":[

  ],
  "C":[
    {
      "name":"Daisy",
      "score":65
    },
    {
      "name":"Emily",
      "score":77
    }
  ],
  "D":[

  ],
  "E":[
    {
      "name":"Brendan",
      "score":49
    }
  ],
  "F":[

  ]
}
```

Comment: when i tried this, I get undefined. In this example, where do you convert the number score to the letter grade?

Comment: Sorry, this result is a bit off. It returns the result for me fine but it seems B, C, D and E  grade also includes students from A grade. I'll rework it a little. Give me a sec.

Comment: This should now work fine if you just define this const function and provide the Student array and Grade Boundaries object to it. If you want full explanation, I'll update it this evening.

Comment: Yes can you please explain! Greatly appreciate this! I am still confused with your answer.. did you need to use my code var studentScores and function toLetterGrade(studentScores)?? I am confused with the letterGrades part. When I removed my code and pasted you answer, i still get undefined!

Comment: No you don't, just just need this function and just call it with the student and grade data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const students = [{

name: 'Daisy',

score: 65,

}, {

name: 'Dan',

score: 99,

}, {

name: 'Emily',

score: 77

}, {

name: 'Brendan',

score: 49

}];

console.log('-----------------------OLD-------------------', students);
setScore(students);
var result = [];
function setScore (students) {
  students.forEach(function (student, i) {
    if (student.score >= 90) {
       student["grade"] = "A";
     } else if (student.score >= 80) {
       student["grade"] = "B";
     } else if (student.score >= 60) {
       student["grade"] = "C";
     } else if (student.score >= 50) {
       student["grade"] = "D";
     } else if (student.score >= 32) {
       student["grade"] = "E";
     } else {
       student["grade"] = "F";
     }
  });
  console.log('-----------------------NEW-------------------', students);
}
```