# Program to enter and calculate the scores for students

Tags: javascript

I have to write a program but I have no idea where to start. I need to use an array and  a function for this.
I need to enter 3 grades from a student for N number of students and calculate the average of each student and  then print a grade.
Finally I need to find the number of students acquired each grade.

```
function grade ()
        {
        var geone  = window.prompt("enter number 1");
        var getwo  = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter number 2"));
        var gthree  = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter number 3"));
//      var ave = gradeone+gradetwo+gradethree/3;
//      if (ave >= 90){
//          document.write("A");
//      }
    }
                var arr = [];
//            for (i=0;i<=9;i++){}
          arr.push(grade);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a javascript function that takes an array with names and scores, and returns array with letter grades and students?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806257/how-to-write-a-javascript-function-that-takes-an-array-with-names-and-scores-an)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function grade() { 
            var arr=[];
            var geone  = prompt("Please enter first","grade one"); 
            arr.push(geone);
            var getwo  = prompt("Please enter second grade","grade two"); 
            arr.push(getwo);
            var gthree  = prompt("Please enter third grade","grade three"); 
            arr.push(gthree);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need exactly. I did a modification to add student name as well. You can get details of each student by iterating the `scoreArray`. I have seperated each part to easily understand. Go line by line, then you will understand the code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var scoreArry = [];
var students = [];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    var noOfStudents = 2; // define the no of students

    for (let i = 1; i <= noOfStudents; i++) {
        var studentName = window.prompt("enter Name");
        var geone = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter number 1"));
        var getwo = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter number 2"));
        var gthree = parseFloat(window.prompt("enter number 3"));

        var student = {
            Name: studentName,
            Score1: geone,
            Score2: getwo,
            Score3: gthree
        };

        students.push(student);
    }

    calculateAverage(students); //calculate the average

    alert('Name: ' + scoreArry[0].Name + ' Grade:' + scoreArry[0].Score);
    alert('Name: ' + scoreArry[1].Name + ' Grade:' + scoreArry[1].Score);
});

function calculateAverage(students) { //calculate the average

    students.forEach((student) => {

        var average = (student.Score1 + student.Score2 + student.Score3) / 3;
        var score = getScore(average);
        var scoreObjct = {  //create gradea object
            Name: student.Name,
            Score: score
        };

        scoreArry.push(scoreObjct); // score array contains all the grades with student name
    })
};

function getScore(everage) { //return the grade
    if (everage >= 90) {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (everage <= 90 && everage >= 50) {
        return 'B'
    }

    // ... add your conditions
};
```

Hope this helps.